# Modify Rename function and creation for image files

Tags: php

This script generates two files, two images, and it renames them.

What i need is that the first image to have the name of the file uploaded, for example : test.jpg, because what this does is convert the image file name to test.jpg.JPG (please don't tell me to remove the part where the extension is added because if i do it it will no longer create the image file) and the second image generated i need it to be something like : test_s.jpg

```
function setFile($src = null) {
$this->ext = strtoupper(pathinfo($src, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
if(is_file($src) && ($this->ext == "JPG" OR $this->ext == "JPEG")) {
$this->img_r = ImageCreateFromJPEG($src);
} elseif(is_file($src) && $this->ext == "PNG") {
$this->img_r = ImageCreateFromPNG($src);
} elseif(is_file($src) && $this->ext == "GIF") {
$this->img_r = ImageCreateFromGIF($src);
}
$this->img_w = imagesx($this->img_r);
$this->img_h = imagesy($this->img_r);
}


function createFile($output_filename = null) {
if($this->ext == "JPG" OR $this->ext == "JPEG") {
imageJPEG($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$output_filename.'.'.$this->ext, $this->quality);
} elseif($this->ext == "PNG") {
imagePNG($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$output_filename.'.'.$this->ext);
} elseif($this->ext == "GIF") {
imageGIF($this->dst_r, $this->uploaddir.$output_filename.'.'.$this->ext);
}
$this->output = $this->uploaddir.$output_filename.'.'.$this->ext;
}

function setUploadDir($dirname) {
$this->uploaddir = $dirname;
}

function flush() {
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
$targetFile = str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

imagedestroy($this->dst_r);
unlink($targetFile);
imagedestroy($this->img_r);

}

}

$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
$targetFile = str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];

move_uploaded_file ($tempFile, $targetFile);

 $image = new Image();
            $image->setFile($targetFile);
            $image->setUploadDir($targetPath);
            $image->resize(640);
            $image->createFile(md5($tempFile));
            $image->resize(100);
            $image->createFile($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
            $image->flush();
}
```

Comment: Your code is long and I don't wish to read it right now. But it will help if you also explain what problem you are having.

Comment: Hey Ariel thanks for replying, i am not having any problem , is just that i can't modify the way it renames the file.. i mean... i know it looks long but what makes the changes is the setFile and createFile function and the last rows of the code!

Comment: You can also help yourself (and others trying to help) by indenting the code properly - it's unnecessarily hard to read currently.

Comment: yes, let me update it...

Comment: Most importantly you should be checking a file has even been uploaded and is the right type currently .php could be uploaded, it will fail your Image class but if i know the `$targetFile` path (which could possibly be pinged on error) I could still access it.

Comment: Yes, the code works fine, but as i said i only need to change the way it's being renamed... the image file!

Comment: @Al_12 I came back to see if I could answer it, but you never fixed the indenting, so I guess you abandoned the question. Sorry I couldn't attempt it earlier.